# refresh en javascript

Tags: javascript

buen dia. estoy con un inconveniente y necesitaria saber como hacerlo. estoy trabajando sobre un carrito de compras. el problema esta en que necesito agregarle un refresh automatico cuando el usuario modifique las cantidades de un producto especifico. a las cantidades las viene cambiando bien, el problema esta cuando le agrego el refresh ya que al actualizarse la pagina la cantidad queda igual que si no la hubiese modificado. luego del segundo refresh se modifica. por qué puede ser?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Saludos como te comentan debes agregar tu codigo como almacenas dichos datos y poder entender mas tu problema y de esta manera darte la mejor opción para ello edita tu pregunta y agrega tu codigo [edit]